# FireFox4 doesn't recognize event object, anybody else having this issue?

Tags: events, firefox, onclick, firebug, firefox4

I wonder if anybody else is having this issue.  I'm using Firefox 4 and I'm debugging a function from an onclick event using Firebug.  Now, to be sure, I checked the stack and it clearly shows that an onclick event was fired.  However, when I type "event" (without quotse) in the watch pane, it says it's undefined.  Why?  Now it recognizes "Event", but not "event".  Is anybody else having this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the code where you bind the event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When debugging inside of your event function, add a watch for `arguments[0]`; this is the event object you are looking for.

Modern, standards-compliant browsers don't use a `window.event` object in the manner that some versions of Internet Explorer do.

In these browsers, the event is passed to the event handler as an argument. So if you do something like the following...

```
function foo(bar) {
   // do stuff
}
document.getElementById("myElement").onclick = foo;
```

...then when `#myElement` is clicked, the browser will execute `foo(bar)`, where `bar` is the event object. If you need to see the event object's details, you would have to set a breakpoint inside of `foo` and add a watch for `bar` or for `arguments[0]`.

Comment: This has been the standard way almost forever.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Well, a quick google search revealed otherwise, with respect to the event object (http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/domevent.shtml).  I realize the article linked is from 2006, but when did FireFox move away from the event object?